# Android wallet with Tor

Tags: privacy, tor, android-wallet, cakewallet

Is there a way to force all connections through Tor on any android wallet?

I tried Cake wallet with Orbot in VPN mode but I don't think it blocks connections without Tor if Orbot is off. I don't have Orbot on all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In Monerujo you can tap on the area within the red circle as seen on this picture:

[image: monerujo-switch-to-tor]

It should then enable Tor support.

Answer (score 0):

There are no wallets I know of with an in-built Tor router. There would be no reason why *any* of the wallets don't *work with* Tor however, like making use of Orbot.

Of course, if you switch Orbot off, you wont be connecting through Tor.

Comment: Mycelium has an option to force connections through Tor.The wallet will connect to the internet even when its not being used for a transaction though won't it?

Answer (score 0):

Never used Cake wallet, don't know if you can set custom nodes there.
If you take monerujo wallet & set an .onion remote node address then your wallet can only connect via Tor (Orbot).

If you want transact safely take your own full node:
https://web.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/tor_wallet.html

Comment: "don't know if you can set custom nodes there" <- you can set custom nodes with both Cake Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Cake wallet with Orbot in VPN mode but I don't think it blocks connections without Tor if Orbot is off. I don't have Orbot on all the time.

You probably should have Orbot running on the background, and only selectively route some of your apps through Orbot. You can do that by enabling the VPN mode, and then tapping on the cog icon under the VPN mode slider.

You can try android VPN settings and enable "Always-on VPN". Also, you need to have the Orbot automatically running on the background, all the time. For that, make sure you take Orbot out of the battery optimization, and make sure that Orbot app has background data connectivity enabled --these two can be done via long-tapping on the Orbot app icon and tapping on the "App Info".